# How to add a cordova plugin to meteor that isn't in the phonegap registry?

Tags: cordova, meteor

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#using-cordova-plugins-directly-in-your-application) you can add a project from the registry or from a tarball url?

```
# add plugin from plugin registry
meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.1

# add plugin from the tarball url
meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tarball/0e61babb65bc1716b957b6294c7fdef3ce6ace79
```

So how do I add [this](https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard) plugin off of github?

Comment: Detailed solution to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624649/how-to-add-cordova-plug-that-havent-registration-on-plugins-cordova-io

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`meteor add cordova:com.verso.cordova.clipboard@https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard/tarball/03fe48b62411cbff22229ca13cc3ac8b282f7945`

Comment: What was the process you used to answer this question?

Comment: Plugin with ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS requires to add those parameters in [MobileConfig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624649/how-to-add-cordova-plug-that-havent-registration-on-plugins-cordova-io/31747292#31747292) file.

Comment: This approach doesn't appear to be working anymore in 1.2.0.1. I get the error "Meteor no longer supports installing Cordova plugins from arbitrary tarball URLs." I tried using the SHA tag on the URL but then get "fetch failed with status code 406." Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

Updated 10/12/2015 for Meteor 1.2.

meteor add cordova:com.verso.cordova.clipboard@https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git#03fe48b62411cbff22229ca13cc3ac8b282f7945

To add to the comment above... to get the @ part.

Before the @: Should be in the plugin.xml in the git repo with the key id.

Next, directly after the @ : https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git

-Get this from the HTTPS link on the right side of the main github repo page.

Next, directly after the #:

-Go to one of the commits in github that you want, the number you need is the last number after 'commit'.

E.G.
https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard/commit/03fe48b62411cbff22229ca13cc3ac8b282f7945

The number would be: 
03fe48b62411cbff22229ca13cc3ac8b282f7945 (The commit hash)

Comment: I can not get this to work on Meteor 1.4, with this plugin: https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer. I try meteor add com.bunkerpalace.cordova.youtubevideoplayer@https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.git#765b5954e78ecf7950099c10bfe5f81133f8f396 but get "error: Version string must look like semver (eg '1.2.3')"

Comment: @MastaBaba Make sure you have cordova: in front. It would be meteor add cordova:com.bunkerpalace.cordova.youtubevideoplayer@github.com/Glitc‌​hbone/....

Answer (score 4):

You can no longer add a Cordova plugin with a tarball URL (I'm using Meteor 1.2.0.1) and there seems to be some sort of bug using the hash value as the docs recommend. Here's what I did instead:

First, I cloned the git project under myapp/private folder. It's important it's private otherwise Meteor will pick-up the www/*.js files and try to compile like normal causing other issues (e.g., "module" or "require" is not defined).

Second, use the following command to add them to your project:

```
meteor add cordova:com.loutilities.qaps.mobile.plugin.phone@file://./private/plugins/cordova-plugin-phone
```

This will them to the cordova-plugins directory along with the other bits they add.

Comment: No, but you can still add directly from a remote Git without cloning locally. See @Mirrorcell 's answer.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.