# How to add cordova plug that haven't registration on plugins.cordova.io?

Tags: cordova, meteor

like these plugin

https://github.com/ArchieGoodwin/SilentShot

https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc

they don't have a tarball url

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git
```

how do i add plugin like this ?

```
meteor add cordova:@https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git
```

Answer (score 10):

**Update**
This works in Meteor 1.2 and 1.3-beta:
`meteor add cordova:pluginID@gitUrl#commithash`

So for the actionsheet plugin:
`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-actionsheet@https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet.git#b93aef15ce4d70c3f9ddf3e4413e68e2ff0c4811`

You could also simply copy that line in .meteor/cordova-plugins file without the 'meteor add cordova' prefix and re-run for ios/android.

---

**Original answer**
For adding 3rd party cordova plugins to meteor which are not in the plugins.cordova.io registry yet, the below method should always work:
For example, to add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet

(breaking it down)

- **meteor add cordova:**
- **nl.x-services.plugins.actionsheet** *(take this **id** from the plugin.xml file in github)*
- **@https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet** *(git repo)*
- **/tarball** *(just the keyword)*
- **/62536f9ee22bfbb8a22ae364d2aaa58bd38e5eb0**  *(get this from the little "Copy SHA" icon next to latest commit at the top in github)*

So the complete line here:

```
meteor add cordova:nl.x-services.plugins.actionsheet@https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet/tarball/62536f9ee22bfbb8a22ae364d2aaa58bd38e5eb0
```

For adding plugin: https://github.com/ArchieGoodwin/SilentShot

`meteor add cordova:biz.incoding.silentshot@https://github.com/ArchieGoodwin/SilentShot/tarball/d123cd881bb211d89c6402d317bfdd3b6302d66b`

Comment: How do you specify sub-folders?

Comment: Attempting to add the branch.io Cordova plugin, we've tried the following command :

meteor add cordova:io.kakaka.branch.sdk@https://github.com/BranchMetrics/tarball/a30665d8b12896d1aad9ee0beb42c516e5fc1f6c

... which pretends to add the plugin, but then, debugging the code, we see no changes.  What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: Marc, did you try adding it the usual way first? 
`meteor add cordova:branch-cordova-sdk@2.0.2`?
Looks like it adds the plugin, but you'll have to set the BRANCH_LIVE_KEY manually in mobile-config.js or config.xml (I did not try this).
Also, please see if it reflects in .meteor/cordova-plugins file.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
You can't target a repo directly but you can target one if its releases:

e.g. For me this worked:

```
meteor add cordova:https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz@2.0.1
```

outputs:

```
added cordova plugin https://github.com/EddyVer
```

Answer (score 0):

For the plugin which requires **additional parameters** then - follow instructions [here.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#cordova-plugins-configuration)

You need to provide your variables in key-val pair in Mobile Config File as described [here.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs)

Answer (score 0):

Since I found it tedious to always look up the right package name and commit hash, and type in the tarball url, I created a little script, [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/chfritz/5e99ffaef3662620cc0b), that uses bash and node to simplify this task a little:

```
./meteor_add_cordova.sh https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin
```