# Meteor Package Error: Cordova Depends Version string must look like semver error

Tags: cordova, meteor, dependencies, package

Working on a mobile package with splashscreen dependencies.

```
Cordova.depends({
'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen': '1.0.0'
});
```

The above works. However, theres a fatal error in version 1.0.0 and I cant use it. Fortunately, they've patched it in a fork of the plugin @ 'https://github.com/TheBosZ/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tarball/891cbf29bf0a7194f637fac4987c1ff4da97f146ss'

So I should be able to do this....

```
Cordova.depends({
     'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen': 'https://github.com/TheBosZ/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tarball/891cbf29bf0a7194f637fac4987c1ff4da97f146ss',
});
```

But its giving me there error Cordova Depends Version string must look like semver error. What gives?

Comment: See this answer for adding the plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068852/how-to-add-a-cordova-plugin-to-meteor-that-isnt-in-the-phonegap-registry. Then try using the version in the package.json file ( https://github.com/TheBosZ/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/package.json), 1.0.1-dev.

Comment: Heh I actually commented in that thread, thats me at the bottom. So in that case, if someone were to download my plugin, they would have to add the forked repo themselves?

Comment: I also cant do this... for some reason. meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.splashscreen@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tarball/b7750760f40c22034c311df94eb46ed216f96f12

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For one, the plugin here: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen

and the git which corresponds to it here: 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

have different package names. Furthermore, meteor actually packages splash screen without all mobile apps. Which is why I was getting errors when I tried to add the correct one to my project. Case closed.